# MVC: I want the Date in my View not to show the default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am displaying a Date in my View. This particular View is one that I use to add data to the database.
On the database the Date field is not null, and that is how it should be. However by virtue of it being not null, the same date field is mapped as not null in the EF generated classes I use. So when I send an empty object of that class to the View, the date is given the default minimum value, which I do not want. Instead I want to see a blank field.
How do I do this?
The date in the View look as follows (not sure this helps anyone, but I know I always get asked for the code)

```
        <tr>
            <td>
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherLeaveDate)%>                    
            </td>
            <td>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.OtherLeaveDate)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherLeaveDate)%>                    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't know the specifics of how this works with EF or MVC, but have you tried making the field a `Nullable<DateTime>` instead of just a `DateTime`?  (Which can also be written in the format `DateTime? mydate`).  This allows the field to contain nothing.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer and is what we use - It can be a `DateTime` in the entity but a `Nullable<DateTime>` in the model - Then you can add mandatory validation to the model to make sure the date is always populated - Just make sure that when mapping to your entity, you map `Model.DateField.Value` not `Model.DateField`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the DefaultValue attribute, here is a [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=421&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for this.